why does pymol not load properly into my flask app?
I am making a webtool in python 3.10.15 using the flask package, where the functional code uses the pymol package. I have installed the pymol package, but there is a discrepency that I cannot figure out how to handle (aside from not using flask, but I prefer not to).
When I import pymol in python in a command prompt, I import the full package:
Python 3.10.15 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Sep 30 2024, 17:41:41) [MSC v.1941 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pymol
>>> print("pymol attributes:",dir(pymol))
pymol attributes: ['CmdException', 'IS_LINUX', 'IS_MACOS', 'IS_WINDOWS', 'IncentiveOnlyException', 'Scratch_Storage', 'Session_Storage', '_NoCmdFinder', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__main__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '_cache', '_cmd', '_colortype', '_ext_gui', '_init_internals', '_invocation', '_launch_no_gui', '_log_file', '_print_statement', '_report_cmd_DLL_problem', '_scene_quit_on_action', '_session_restore_tasks', '_session_save_tasks', '_stdin_reader_thread', '_view_dict', '_view_dict_sc', 'adapt_to_hardware', 'api', 'checking', 'cmd', 'colorprinting', 'colorramping', 'commanding', 'completing', 'computing', 'constants', 'constants_palette', 'controlling', 'copy', 'creating', 'diagnosing', 'editing', 'editor', 'epymol', 'exec_deferred', 'exec_str', 'experimenting', 'exporting', 'externing', 'feedingback', 'finish_launching', 'fitting', 'get_capabilities', 'get_version_message', 'glutThread', 'guess_pymol_path', 'gui', 'helping', 'importing', 'internal', 'invocation', 'keyboard', 'keywords', 'launch', 'launch_gui', 'licensing', 'lock_api', 'lock_api_data', 'lock_api_glut', 'lock_api_status', 'locking', 'math', 'monitoring', 'morphing', 'movie', 'moving', 'moving2', 'os', 'parsing', 'preset', 'prime_pymol', 'program_manager', 'properties', 'pymol', 'querying', 're', 'save_shortcut', 'selecting', 'selector', 'session', 'setting', 'setup_environ', 'shortcut', 'shortcut_dict', 'shortcut_manager', 'stereochemistry', 'stored', 'sys', 'thread', 'threading', 'time', 'timeline', 'timeline_programs', 'tools', 'traceback', 'undo', 'util', 'viewing', 'wizarding']

But when I import and run it in the flask app, it does not import the full package:
pymol attributes: ['__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']

do anyone know why this is happening and what I can do ?
I just want to get the pymol package working in flask
